# What does 'discarding a question' mean for the Rubber Ducky hat?

Tags: support, winter-bash, winter-bash-2019

Apparently I need to press the discard button on a meta or main site to get the Rubber Ducky hat. However, I do not know how to discard a post. Is that the same as deleting it?

Answer (score 3):

There's an autosave feature for questions you're writing. It'll trigger after a certain period of time (a minute or so), and then a 'Discard' button will become visible:

[image]

Discarding is definitely *not* posting and deleting it, that would give much noise on the front page. Hats, like badges, are meant to encourage positive behaviour; in this case, it's meant to simulate realizing the answer to your own question and *not* posting it.